# display more than one record >curdate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Attempting to display different data in a table, but am only gettting the most recent result.  The only thing I have changed in my code is adding the >CURDATE rather than the most simple *.  it has stopped displaying all of the results.  can you help?

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tripdata WHERE date  > CURDATE()");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    echo "<table class='mainpics'>";  
  echo    "<tr><td><a class='mainpic' href='". $row['pageurl'] ."'><img class='mainpic' src='" .  $row['mainpic'] . "'/></a></td></tr>";

  echo "</table>";
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What would be your expected output? What are you trying to do? What data do you currently have in that table?

Comment: the table data is an image source and href for that image to act as a clickable list.  The table is so each image(link) will be displayed vertically.  Thanks

Comment: You said you had only added changed `where date > curdate()` to the query and you're only getting 1 result now. All the rest of the code should keep working the same way but you're just getting less data. Now, when I said `table` I meant `tripdata`. The `select` statement is the only thing that matters in there

Comment: I have rewritten the code and it works now.  But I can't see any difference in what i had before!

Comment: Be careful using the 'date' keyword as a column name. Sometimes, mysql will interpret this as the beginning of a date function and not as a column name. Can be solved by using qualifiers.